# Sending html email from linux system using bash?

Tags: html, linux, bash, email, outlook

[Question Edited]: XHTML Code validated
I am trying to send an mail to outlook 2016 server from my linux system and cant seem to find "why the received email (on my outlook server) only shows html code and not the html style page, when viewing myhtml.html on html viewer"

```
echo "Subject: Build message
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"us-ascii\"" > myhtml.html

       MAIL_CONTENT="

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
              <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
              <div id="body"></div>
              <p><font size="4" color="blue">DUMMY LINE</font></p>
              <pre>"DUMMY MSG"</pre>
              -------------------------------------------------------------------------

</body>
</html>
"

echo "$MAIL_CONTENT" >> myhtml.html
```

The above code saved in myhtml.html file which I send as email using the linux command

```
mail dummy@address.com < myhtml.html
```

I have tried the link given as suggestion but still I am seeing the email message as html code.